# primordials is not defined in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm facing an issue of 'primordials is not defined' when I try to run the node services ,have tried multiple solution provided on stackoverflow ,but none of them seems to work.

Solution Tried
1)Delete the node_modules folder and re-install

2. In package.json added

   "resolutions": {
   "graceful-fs": "^4.2.4"
   }

but still facing the same issue when i try to run the service ,can someone please guide on how to fix the same

Have added the image of the error below

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you add `./src/server.ts` content

Comment: @kennarddh its just connections that are part of server.ts